# Changing element style attribute dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hav a certain style sheet for a div. Now i want to modify one attribute of div dynamically using js.

How can i do it?

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.padding-top = "10px";
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

It's almost correct.

Since the `-` is a javascript operator, you can't really have that in property names. If you were setting, `border` or something single-worded like that instead, your code would work just fine.

However, the thing you need to remember for `padding-top`, and for any hyphenated attribute name, is that in javascript, you remove the hyphen, and make the next letter uppercase, so in your case that'd be `paddingTop`.

There are some other exceptions. JavaScript has some reserved words, so you can't set `float` like that, for instance. Instead, in some browsers you need to use `cssFloat` and in others `styleFloat`. It is for discrepancies like this that it is recommended that you use a framework such as jQuery, that handles browser incompatibilities for you...

Answer (score 271):

In addition to other answers, if you want to use the dash notition for style properties, you can also use:

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style["padding-top"] = "10px";
```

[**edit 2023**] Very old answer. For who it may concern: I created a small library to change styling dynamically [@Github](https://github.com/KooiInc/LifeCSS).

Comment: Me neither, this is really useful for dynamic functions, one can pass the style as a string value, then set the style and value. Great solution.

Comment: Also, adding to what @raphie says, you can also use `document.getElementById("xyz").style["paddingTop"] = '10px'`.

Answer (score 41):

**There is also `style.setProperty` function:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.setProperty('padding-top', '10px');

// version with !important priority
document.getElementById("xyz").style.setProperty('padding-top', '10px', 'important');
```

Answer (score 19):

I resolve similar problem with:

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.padding = "10px 0 0 0";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The con of doing this way is that you get the padding for other sides set to `0`. And sometimes you don't want that.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you have HTML like this:

```
<div id='thediv'></div>
```

If you want to modify the style attribute of this div, you'd use

```
document.getElementById('thediv').style[ATTRIBUTE] = '[VALUE]'
```

Replace `[ATTRIBUTE]` with the style attribute you want. Remember to remove '-' and make the following letter uppercase.

**Examples**

```
document.getElementById('thediv').style.display = 'none'; //changes the display
document.getElementById('thediv').style.paddingLeft = 'none'; //removes padding
```

Comment: As stated in the accepted answer, there are some exceptions. Like `float`.

Answer (score 9):

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.padding-top = '10px';
```

will be

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style["paddingTop"] = '10px';
```

Answer (score 9):

```
document.getElementById("xyz").setAttribute('style','padding-top:10px');
```

would also do the job.

Comment: The downside of doing this way is that you get any other inline style removed. That's because you're replacing the entire attribute value. I guess getting the current style, checking for an existing value for the property you want to set, and then add/replace by the desired value is a better solution.

Comment: Agreed. But the OP needed a solution closer to what he was already doing which was not taking into account your use case. This is one of the simplest ways to achieve that, but it is surely not the best.

Comment: @GustavoStraube, I wouldn't call it a downside. In many cases this is exactly what the developer wants to do - i.e. overwrite the element's style. I would call it a consequence of doing it this way.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using a function, which accepts the element id and an object containing the CSS properties, to handle this. This way you write multiple styles at once and use standard CSS property syntax.

```
//function to handle multiple styles
function setStyle(elId, propertyObject) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elId);
    for (var property in propertyObject) {
        el.style[property] = propertyObject[property];
    }
}

setStyle('xyz', {'padding-top': '10px'});
```

Better still you could store the styles in a variable, which will make for much easier property management e.g.

```
var xyzStyles = {'padding-top':'10px'}
setStyle('xyz', xyzStyles);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

**Surprised** that I did not see the below *query selector* way solution,

```
document.querySelector('#xyz').style.paddingTop = "10px"
```

*CSSStyleDeclaration* solutions, an example of the accepted answer

```
document.getElementById('xyz').style.paddingTop = "10px";
```

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementById('id').style = 'left: 55%; z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; opacity: 0; display: none;';
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

I change css style in Javascript function.

But Uncaught TypeError: bild is null .

If I run it in a normal html file it work.

```
CODE:

  var text = document.getElementById("text");
var bild = document.getElementById("bild");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

bild.style["background-image"] = "url('stock-bild-portrait-of-confident-senior-business-woman-standing-in-office-with-her-arms-crossed-mature-female-1156978234.jpg')";
//bild.style.background-image = "url('stock-bild-portrait-of-confident-senior-business-woman-standing-in-office-with-her-arms-crossed-mature-female-1156978234.jpg')";

 //  bild.style["background-image"] =  "url('" +  defaultpic + "')";
 alert (bild.style["background-image"]) ;
 bild.style["background-size"] = "300px";
 bild.style["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
 bild.style["background-position"] = "center";
 bild.style["border-radius"] = "50%";
 bild.style["background-clip"] = "border-box";
 bild.style["transition"] = "background-size 0.2s";
 bild.style["transition-timing-function"] = "cubic-bezier(.07,1.41,.82,1.41)";
 bild.style["display"] = "block";
 bild.style["width"] = "100px";
 bild.style["height"] = "100px";

 bild.style["text-decoration"] = "none";
 bild.style["cursor"] = "pointer";
 bild.style["overflow"] = "hidden";
 bild.style["text-indent"] = "100%";
 bild.style["white-space"] = "nowrap";

 container.style["position"] = "relative";
 container.style["font-family"] = "Arial";

 text.style["position"] = "center";
 text.style["bottom"] = "5px";
 text.style["left"] = "1px";
 text.style["color"] = "white";
```