# Javascript: Change backgroundPosition for two background images on one element

Tags: javascript, css

My Problem: 
I have two background images on the body tag one floating left and one right. The left image has a left padding of 50px and the right image has a right padding of 50px. I need to change the left padding for the left image and the right padding for the right image via javascript (not jquery).

Thanks for your help! :)

```
#body{
      background:url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/w3css.gif') no-repeat 50px 0px,
      url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/w3css.gif') no-repeat top right 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundPosition = '150px 0, 100px 0';
```

The first `150px 0` is for the left image and `100px 0` is for the second image.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/9a32b/

Comment: This works, I should of known to just use a comma. Maybe I drank too much coffee today. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the tag an id like id="body" then,

`document.getElementById("body").style["padding-left"] = "50px";`
`document.getElementById("body").style["padding-right"] = "50px";`

see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191478/changing-element-style-attribute-dynamically-using-javascript)