# Setting element styles with javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I've got some sizing styles that I'm setting on the fly. I generally develop in chrome, and was directly setting attributes on the `style` attribute of the element like so:

```
element.style['padding-right'] = computedRightPadding + 'px';
```

I found recently that this does not work in firefox (version 24.6.0). The attribute on the element object looks like it's set correctly, but there is no change in the actual styling of the element. I've got a fiddle showing this [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8w7/)

What's a good, cross-browser way of setting this style with javascript? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191478/changing-element-style-attribute-dynamically-using-javascript), which says to do the method I'm currently using, which doesn't work. I'd rather not rely on an external library for what seems like it should be a trivial operation.

Comment: `element.style.paddingRight` will work everywhere. And,.. it won't create a string instance just for dereferencing the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `parent.style.paddingRight = '100px';`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Cn8w7/1/)**

Or  `parent.setAttribute('style', 'padding-right:100px;');`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y89yU/)**

Comment: [CSS Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference)

Comment: But the second alternative resets all the other style properties defined on the element (via the style attribute, not via classes). Check: http://jsfiddle.net/y89yU/1/ - `padding-right` is gone.

Comment: @techfoobar Yep.  What you really want there if you want to use the hyphenated name is `parent.style.setProperty('padding-right', '100px')`.