# How to Change the Fixed Position Styles Dynamically - using JavaScript. Set position name, Values

Tags: javascript, css, position

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.style.position = "fixed";

btn.style.bottom = "100px";

btn.style.right = "100px";



/* here the bottom and right is not fixed - and value 100px is also not fixed
- this values are given user  - a user may select postion to top left, top right, bottom left */ 

/* An example - this are user given values - and based on this values how can i set the positon  */
var position_1 = "top";
var position_2 = "right"

var position_1_value = "100px";
var postion_2_value = "100px";



var dynamic_btn = document.querySelector('.dynamic-btn');

dynamic_btn.style.position = "fixed";

/* dynamic_btn.style.top = position_1_value; */
dynamic_btn.style.position_1 = position_1_value;

/* dynamic_btn.style.right = postion_2_value; */
dynamic_btn.style.position_2 = postion_2_value;
```

```html
<button class="btn">hello</button>

<button class="dynamic-btn">Dynamic button</button>
```

Have to change the Styles using JavaScript

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.style.position = "fixed";
btn.style.bottom = "100px";
btn.style.right = "100px";
```

This is some thing like static. - with know values we did;

But In our case user will give the position name, value.
User may choose any position - bottom, right, top, left  and can add any value like 10px, 100px

something I tried, but unable to add the position name

```
var position_1 = "top";
var position_2 = "right"
var position_1_value = "100px";
var postion_2_value = "100px";

var dynamic_btn = document.querySelector('.dynamic-btn');

dynamic_btn.style.position = "fixed";

/* dynamic_btn.style.top = position_1_value; */
dynamic_btn.style.position_1 = position_1_value;

/* dynamic_btn.style.right = postion_2_value; */
dynamic_btn.style.position_2 = postion_2_value;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oj0mxbs5/16/)

Comment: Use square brackets notation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the style using square brackets:

```
dynamic_btn.style[position_1] = position_1_value;
```

This way, you can access values of dynamically named properties.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe can help you, let me know if it's right or you need some more info.

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.setProperty('padding-top', '10px');

// version with !important priority
document.getElementById("xyz").style.setProperty('padding-top', '10px', 'important');
```

If you need you can replace "getElementById" with "getElementsByClassName".

I've found the answer in this question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754513/6821907

Answer (score 0):

[This JSFiddle could help you](https://jsfiddle.net/oj0mxbs5/44/), basically by setting the button with a relative position inside a div with a specific height you are allowed to move the control freely inside that div

*JavaScript*

```
document.querySelector('.move').addEventListener('click', function () {
 var dynamicBtn = document.querySelector('.dynamic-btn');
 var top = document.querySelector('#top');
 var left = document.querySelector('#left');

 dynamicBtn.style.position = 'relative';
 dynamicBtn.style.top = top.value + 'px';
 dynamicBtn.style.left = left.value + 'px';
});
```

*CSS*

```
.main {
  height: 100%;
}

.controls {
  height: 10%;
}

.space {
  height: 90%;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="move">move</button>
    <input type="number" placeholder="top" id="top" value="10" />
    <input type="number" placeholder="left" id="left" value="20" />
  </div>

  <div class="space">
    <button class="dynamic-btn">Dynamic button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: friend, the major issue is on how to change the positions - top, left, bottom, right. any how thanks for your answer.