# How to change onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an alert page that has the user click a button to see if an alert is seen or not. In my code I have the button changing text but not color how do I get the button to change color when I click on it.

```js
document.getElementById("seen").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(event) {
    if (event.target.value === "unacknowledged") {
      event.target.value = "acknowledge";

    } else {
      event.target.value = "unacknowledged";
    }
  },
  false
);
```

```css
#seen {
  background-color: #1da4f1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="seen" value="unacknowledged">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing element style attribute dynamically using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191478/changing-element-style-attribute-dynamically-using-javascript)

Comment: Try adding tags like "javascript" that way more people see it.

Comment: set a class? set a style?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a lot of ways

## first and easiest

You can insert an style on the element with `event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

[learn more here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

## second and more clean way

Create a class and add the class to the element after clicking

css

```
.button-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

js

```
event.target.classList.add('button-red');
```

[learn more here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
document.getElementById('seen').addEventListener('click', function(event) 
  {
  this.classList.toggle('hack')
  }, false )
```

```css
#seen {
  background-color : #1da4f1;
  border           : none;
  border-radius    : 4px;
  color            : white;
  padding          : 2px 32px;
  text-align       : center;
  text-decoration  : none;
  display          : inline-block;
  font-size        : 14px;
  }
#seen.hack { 
  background-color : #e3f11d;
  color            : black;
  }
#seen::after { content: 'unacknowledged'}
#seen.hack::after { content: 'acknowledged'}
```

```html
<button id="seen"></button>
```

Or (without pseudo class after)

```js
document.getElementById('seen').addEventListener('click', function(event) 
  {
  this.textContent = this.classList.toggle('hack') 
                   ? 'acknowledged'
                   : 'unacknowledged'
  }, false );
```

```css
#seen {
  background-color : #1da4f1;
  border           : none;
  border-radius    : 4px;
  color            : white;
  padding          : 2px 32px;
  text-align       : center;
  text-decoration  : none;
  display          : inline-block;
  font-size        : 14px;
  }
#seen.hack { 
  background-color : #e3f11d;
  color            : black;
  }
```

```html
<button id="seen">unacknowledged</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

***To achieve what you want just simply add following two lines of code***

`document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "green"`
`document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "#1da4f1"`

```
if (event.target.value === "unacknowledged") {
      event.target.value = "acknowledge";
      document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "green";

    } else {
      event.target.value = "unacknowledged";
      document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "#1da4f1";
    }
```

```js
document.getElementById("seen").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(event) {
    if (event.target.value === "unacknowledged") {
      event.target.value = "acknowledge";
      document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "green"

    } else {
      event.target.value = "unacknowledged";
      document.getElementById("seen").style["background-color"] = "#1da4f1"
    }
  },
  false
);
```

```css
#seen {
  background-color: #1da4f1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="seen" value="unacknowledged">
```