# Why doesn't style.display take affect for me?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attr

I'm trying to make a progress indicator and an error message. Initially I set the style="display: none;" attributes.
I would like to change it to style="display: block;" with JS, but my code does not take affect.
Could you please help what am I missing?

HTML part:

```
<div class="loader" id="loading-indicator" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="error-message" id="error-message" style="display: none;">
        An error has occured
    </div>
```

JS part:

```
export const initForm = () =>{
    const displayLoadingIndicator = document.getElementById('loading-indicator');
    const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message')
    document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', async eventObjeckt =>{
        const country = document.querySelector('#country-name').value;
        console.log("CHECKPOINT 4: submit button was pushed");
        console.log(`CHECKPOINT 3: ${country}`);
        eventObjeckt.preventDefault();
        // loadingIndicator START 
        displayLoadingIndicator.style.display = "block";
        console.log("After setting displayLoadingIndicator.style.display to 'block' : ", displayLoadingIndicator)
        try{
            getData(country)
        }catch(e){
            errorMessage.style.display = 'block';

        }
        displayLoadingIndicator.style.display = "none";
        console.log("After setting back to displayLoadingIndicator.style.display to 'none': ", displayLoadingIndicator)
        // loadingIndicator END
    })
```

I console.log-ed the HTML elements before and after the .style.display = 'block' commands, but they all look like this:

```
<div class="loader" id="loading-indicator" style="display: none;"></div>
```

so the .style.display = "block"; did not take effect.

Thank you

Comment: does this answer your questions: [Changing Element Style Attribute Dynamically Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191478/changing-element-style-attribute-dynamically-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript functions are blocking and [`console.log` is lazy about evaluating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects).

You set it to `block`, then some JavaScript runs, then you set it back to `none`. In that time, there is no repaint of the display (because the JS blocks it) and by the time *either* `console.log` statement looks at the element it is back to `none`.

If `getData(country)` is a time consuming operation, consider farming it off to a Webworker, and setting `block` when the webworker messages the main process that it has finished doing the work. [MDN has a tutorial on webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).